# cakephp 2.x/uploadify: changing session id forces logout

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication

I am messing with uploadify and cakephp (2.x) atm but I cant get it to work. It worked an hour ago and now it's magically destroyed.

My cakephp application features a backend with a simple authentification. Users can upload images with uploadify and when uploadify sends the image to my controller I simply attach the sessionid as a parameter.

Unfortunately I receive an HTTP-ERROR (HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified). Excluding the controller's method from the authetification ($this->allow(...)) does help. Therefore I assume something fails concerning the authentification / session.

The next step I took was that I checked whether the SID got transmitted and it did.

That's why I thought that I narrowed down the problem to the point where the session id becomes set. That happens in the controller's beforeFilter in a way like:

if ( isset($this->params['session_id']) ) { $this->Session->id($this->params['session_id']); }

When I add that piece of code something happens that I can't explain/understand:

I try to upload an image via uploadify in the backened and it returns with an HTTP error. Hitting F5 / Refresh causes a redirection to the login-form although I am actually logged in! I also get a new SID.

And I am 99% sure that the session_id param is transmitted to the controller and that $this->Session->id() should set the correct SID.

So why do I get logged out?

I do NOT get logged out when I manually invoke the URL to my controller (http://localhost/myapp/backend/upload/12345   *12345 being the SID!). Only if uploadify does it.

I also tried setting the Cake Security Level to low but it won't help. It also happens when I commit the session ID with the scriptData parameter to the uploadify js script.

When I use that line of code in my controller's method:

```
$this->Session->id(1234);
echo $this->Session->id();
```

the method echos 1234 but on my backend's page view it still states the original session value. What the hell is going on?

Is there anybody who might have a clue what is going on or at least who knows why Session/Auth behaves the way it does?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Best regards

---

i **fixed** it.

my controller's beforeFilter() function looked like that:

```
parent::beforeFilter();
if ( isset($this->params['session_id']) ) { $this->Session->id($this->params['session_id']); }
```

but the session id has to be set BEFORE invoking the parent::beforeFilter() function.

```
if ( isset($this->params['session_id']) ) { $this->Session->id($this->params['session_id']); }
parent::beforeFilter();
```

damn -.- wasted so much time on it..

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, the way I solved it was by creating a component: `SessionRescueComponent` and declare that in your `AppController` FIRST:

```
public $components = array( 'SessionRescue', 'Auth', 'Security' ... );
```

In your new component:

```
class SessionRescueComponent extends Component {

  /**
     * Restore session from POST fields if possible.
     *
     * This is required because flash plugin uses a different
     * session (id and user agent) from the application one.
     *
     * @param Object &$controller pointer to calling controller
  */

       public function initialize( & $controller ) {

            if ( ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) and ( ( strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) == 'shockwave flash' ) or ( strpos( strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) , 'adobe flash player') !== false))) and 
                isset($controller->data['Model']['session_id']) and ( $controller->action == 'imageupload' || $controller->action == 'upload' || $controller->action == 'flashupload' ) ) {

                session_id( $controller->data['Model']['session_id'] );
                session_start();

            }
       }
}
```

**If you want to set your session the cake way**

inside your class:

```
public $components = array( 'Session' );
```

Then inside your IF block:

```
$this->Session->id( $controller->data['Model']['session_id'] );
$this->Session->start();
```

This will essentially be invoked before anything is done with the application, and should set your session ID before anything can get lost.

Good luck!